# Vim shorter shortcut variant for ci' or ci"

Tags: vim, shortcut

What **one character** shortcut is for: Find first occurrence of quotes on a line, delete text inside them and jump to the insert mode?

I know that there is a way: `ci'` or `ci"` atd... but I know that there's even shorter way to do it.
Recently I encountered with this shortcut tip somewhere on the internet but I unfortunately forgot it.

I think it's native vim shortcut and there's no need to create some kind of mapping...

EDIT:
Now I'm not sure if it's one character shortcut but it's definitely much faster way.

Comment: Is `ci'` and `ci"` not short enough? I don't think it gets simpler than that without writing your own mappings.

Comment: In some point you're right, but it was wonderful feeling when I did it even faster xD. I tried it so I know that there is something... and I don't have mapping for that. Maybe it's combined with some modifier key... I don't remember...It disrupts me that now I dont know it. ps:I have installed surround plugin but I did not find the shortcut in the documentation.

Comment: There is nothing shorter built in. ci" is the shortest sequence for "find the next quote, delete everything between quotes, and enter insert mode" unless you write a custom mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above say, there is no built-in way to make this shorter. You can make a custom mapping for it if you are that keen on shortening it. I would advice you against doing a one-character mapping for it because such mappings are precious, but that's up to you. There are many ways you could map this, such as overwriting existing but less useful mappings such as `;` and `,`. One way would be to do something like this (you will need to set your `mapleader` to something convenient; `:let mapleader=","` seems to be common):

```
nnoremap <leader>' ci'
nnoremap <leader>" ci"
```

You may also be interested in [Wildfire](https://github.com/gcmt/wildfire.vim) which can ease selecting blocks between quotes and other things, or in [SmartPairs](https://github.com/gorkunov/smartpairs.vim), which is similar.